# Selenium web scraping is giving me wrong row, I don't where I did wrong?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

Hello I am web scrapping a site

here is my code

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
import pandas as pd
import time


driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))

search_url = "https://dealt.ae/collections/laptops"
driver.get(search_url)
time.sleep(3)

ALL_ITEMS = []
item = ["", "", "", ""]
all_laptops = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//div[@class="product-collection products-grid row"]')
grades = all_laptops[0].find_elements(By.XPATH, '//div[@class="product-top"]/span[@class="product-metafild"]')
for i in range(len(grades)):
    item[0] = grades[i].text
    description = all_laptops[0].find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'product-title')
    item[1] = description[i].text
    old_price= all_laptops[0].find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'old-price')
    item[2] = old_price[i].text
    special_price= all_laptops[0].find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'special-price')
    item[3] = special_price[i].text
    print(item)
    ALL_ITEMS.append(item.copy())    
                
for item in ALL_ITEMS:
    print(item)

my_df = pd.DataFrame(ALL_ITEMS)
my_df.to_csv('laptop.csv', index=False, header=False)
```

It is giving me a wrong output (rows), with grade of someone else product and price of someone else product. Please tell me where i did wrong.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It is because your are not selecting the perfect class name which is a common thing in all laptops and have all the details about that particular laptop.

Here is the full working code

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
import pandas as pd
import time


driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))

# set the page parameter its upto 14 for 24 items per page
search_url = "https://dealt.ae/collections/laptops?page=1"
driver.get(search_url)
time.sleep(3)

ALL_ITEMS = []
item = ["", "", "", ""]
all_laptops = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//div[@class="product-collection products-grid row"]')
all_grids = all_laptops[0].find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'grid-item')
print(f"Getting {len(all_grids)} laptops")
for i in range(len(all_grids)):
    all_laptops = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//div[@class="product-collection products-grid row"]')
    all_grids = all_laptops[0].find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'grid-item')
    grades = all_grids[i].find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'product-metafild')
    item[0] = grades.text
    description =all_grids[i].find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'product-title')
    item[1] = description.text
    try:
        old_price= all_grids[i].find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'old-price')
        item[2] = old_price.text
        special_price= all_grids[i].find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'special-price')
        item[3] = special_price.text
    except NoSuchElementException:
        regular_price= all_grids[i].find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'price-regular')
        item[2]= regular_price.text
        item[3]= ""
    print(item)
    ALL_ITEMS.append(item.copy())    
                
for item in ALL_ITEMS:
    print(item)

my_df = pd.DataFrame(ALL_ITEMS)
my_df.to_csv('laptop_13.csv', index=False, header=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not pulling the information for each laptop within the loop. Here's a cleaner way of doing it:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import pandas as pd
import time


driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
search_url = "https://dealt.ae/collections/laptops"
driver.get(search_url)
time.sleep(3)

all_items = []

#find all_laptop containers
all_laptops = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.grid-item.col-6.col-md-4.col-lg-3')

for row in all_laptops:
    # Go through each row and create find the elements inside that container we need(laptop)
    grade = row.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'span.product-metafild')
    grade = grade.text.strip() if grade else ''

    description = row.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'product-title')
    description = description[0].text.strip() if description else ''

    old_price = row.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.old-price')
    old_price = old_price[0].text.strip() if old_price else ''
    
    special_price = row.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'special-price')
    special_price = special_price[0].text.strip() if special_price else ''
    
    # Create a temporary dictionary and append to the main list
    temp_dict = {'Grade':grade, 'Description': description, 'Old Price': old_price, 'Special Price': special_price}
    all_items.append(temp_dict)

my_df = pd.DataFrame(all_items)
my_df.to_csv('laptop.csv', index=False, header=False)

driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

Just using API url, scrape the desired data static way  where you also can make the pagination easily

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
url = "https://dealt.ae/collections/laptops?page=1"

req=requests.get(url)
print(req)
soup = BeautifulSoup(req.content, "lxml")
lst={}

description =[x.get_text().strip() for x in soup.select('.product-title span')][2:][::2]

old_price =[x.get_text().strip() for x in soup.select('.old-price')][2:][::2]

special_price =[x.get_text().strip() for x in soup.select('.special-price')][2:][::2]

df= pd.DataFrame(data=list(zip(description,old_price,special_price)))
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
BLACK and GOLD PARTY DECORATIONS Perfect Adult...  Dhs. 1,675.00    Dhs. 815.00
1   Lenovo L450 Thinkpad Laptop  - Intel Core i5-5...  Dhs. 1,630.00    Dhs. 760.00
2   Dell Latitude E7470 Laptop - Intel Core I5 6th...  Dhs. 1,700.00    Dhs. 830.00
3   Dell Latitude 3160 11.6 Inch Touchscreen Displ...  Dhs. 2,900.00  Dhs. 1,599.00
4   Lenovo T450 Thinkpad Laptop  - Intel Core i5-4...  Dhs. 2,900.00  Dhs. 1,550.00
5   Hp Elitebook Folio 9480m 14.1" Display Ci5-4th...  Dhs. 2,725.00  Dhs. 1,865.00
6   Macbook Air A1466 (2017) Laptop With 13.3-Inch...  Dhs. 3,314.00  Dhs. 1,465.00
7   Macbook Air A1466 (2017) Laptop With 13.3-Inch...  Dhs. 2,624.00  Dhs. 1,165.00
8   Dell Precision 7510 Laptop - Intel Core I7 6th...  Dhs. 2,509.00  Dhs. 1,115.00
9   Dell Precision 3510  Laptop - Intel Core I5 6t...  Dhs. 2,854.00  Dhs. 1,265.00
10  Dell Latitude E7490 Laptop - Intel Core I5 7th...  Dhs. 2,739.00  Dhs. 1,215.00
11  Dell Latitude E7490 Laptop - Intel Core I5 7th...  Dhs. 3,084.00  Dhs. 1,365.00
12  Dell Latitude E7480 Touch Screen Laptop - Inte...  Dhs. 2,969.00  Dhs. 1,315.00
13  Dell Latitude E7480 Touch Screen Laptop - Inte...  Dhs. 3,084.00  Dhs. 1,365.00
14  Dell Latitude E7480 Laptop - Intel Core I7 6th...  Dhs. 2,969.00  Dhs. 1,315.00
15  Dell Latitude E7480 Laptop - Intel Core I7 6th...  Dhs. 2,739.00  Dhs. 1,215.00
16  Dell Latitude E7480 Laptop - Intel Core I5 7th...  Dhs. 2,624.00  Dhs. 1,165.00
17  Dell Latitude E7480 Laptop - Intel Core I5 7th...  Dhs. 2,739.00  Dhs. 1,215.00
18  Dell Latitude E7480 Laptop - Intel Core I5 6th...  Dhs. 2,325.00  Dhs. 1,035.00
19  Dell Latitude E7480 Laptop - Intel Core I5 6th...  Dhs. 2,210.00    Dhs. 985.00
20  Dell Latitude E7470 Laptop - Intel Core I7 6th...  Dhs. 2,049.00    Dhs. 915.00
```